# php $_POST['data'.$i] increase number `$i`

Tags: php, jquery, post

Maybe this is a strange question. I have many button pass value with jquery. they are very similar. so i tried to combine them with number increase.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
for (var i = 0; i <5; i++){
    $('.click'+i).click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php", 
            dataType: "html",
            type: 'POST', 
            data: "data"+i+"="+i,
            success: function(data){ 
                $("#result"+i).html(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
});
</script>

<a class="click1">aaa</a>
<a class="click2">bbb</a>
<a class="click3">ccc</a>
<a class="click4">ddd</a>
<a class="click5">eee</a>
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
echo '<div id="result'.$i.'"></div>';
}
?>
```

but `$_POST['data'.$i]` is an unexpected T_ECHO, so how to write so that I will not reapeat work in data.php

data.php

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
$_POST['data'.$i]{
    echo $_POST['data'.$i];
//some stuff, most are similer, less code diferent use if else for $_POST['data1'] - $_POST['data5']
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript code is not correct. All click handlers will reference the same `i` (the same value). Search for *javascript closure in loop*  or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    echo $_POST['data'.$i];
}
```

is ok

Also it's possible to use `data[]` or `data[5]` as field name.
It will be available in **array** `$_POST['data']`

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: oops, this is not a fix for the original poster's concern, but rather another problem that this code will exhibit (which I thought was OP's question). I'm keeping this here for posterity.*

This looks like it exhibits one common problem with JS closures. Let's say you have this JavaScript code.

```
for (var i=1; i<5; i++) {
    $('.click'+i).click(function() {
         alert("Clicked " + i);
    });
 }
```

You are probably expecting:

```
$(".click1").click(function() { alert("Clicked 1"); });
$(".click2").click(function() { alert("Clicked 2"); });
$(".click3").click(function() { alert("Clicked 3"); });
$(".click4").click(function() { alert("Clicked 4"); });
$(".click5").click(function() { alert("Clicked 5"); });
```

In reality, this is:

```
$(".click1").click(function() { alert("Clicked 6"); });
$(".click2").click(function() { alert("Clicked 6"); });
$(".click3").click(function() { alert("Clicked 6"); });
$(".click4").click(function() { alert("Clicked 6"); });
$(".click5").click(function() { alert("Clicked 6"); });
//
//               Notice that they're all "6" --^
```

...Because everything inside the `click` event uses the same instance of `i`, which at the end of the loop, becomes 6.

### Fix number one

This version will create a new variable scope for each iteration which will "bake" the value of `i` into a newly-created function.

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    $('.click'+i).click((function(i) {
         return (function() {
             alert("Clicked " + i);
         });
    })(i));
 }
```

This is a fairly difficult concept to grasp. Google around for something like "iteration closures javascript" to find more in-depth explanations of what's going on.

### Fix number two

This one is less-elegant but easier to understand.

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    // Store the 'i' in the element itself...
    $('.click'+i).data('index', i);

    // ...then retrieve it later
    $('.click'+i).click(function () {
         alert("Clicked " + $(this).data('index'));
    });
 }
```

This one stores the value of `i` inside the element itself using jQuery's `.data` method. Instead of referencing `i` in the event, you use `$(this).data('index')`.

Answer (score -1):

if you give like this

```
 for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
 { 
  echo $_POST['data'.$i]; 
 }//it seams like $_POST['data'1];
```

so just try

```
 for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
 { 
  echo $_POST["data$i"]; 
 }
```